# Android Studio downloads different gradles each project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know there is some question like it before but this is somehow different.

I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.6.3 
and then each time I make a project it needs to download gradle depends on that project

for example for Kotlin it needs gradle 5.6.4 and for my last project it needs 2.14.2

I also downloaded gradle 6.2.2 for root (~.gradle\wrapper\dists )

and it also cant recognize the gradles that Android Studio has downloaded last time (in root) and it needs to download them again :(

Comment: you shoudn't link pictures, instead paste the error, or relevant information in your post

Comment: As OP being the new user, @al3c he does not have the right yet to include images i suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the gradle version that your project uses and the gradle plugin version that the android studio uses.

Take a look at [Gradle plugin version and gradle version chart](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) chart to make sure your have compatible versions of the gradle plugin and the actual gradle which is exposed by your gradle wrapper class.

## EDIT

You should not worry what version of gradle are being downloaded inside .gradle folder in your root directory. There is a reason why that folder is hidden by default and why gradle wrapper is offered by the Gradle.

The only factor you need to take in consideration is what Gradle version you want to use in your project, set that version in the Gradle Wrapper and make sure your IDE's gradle plugin's version is compatible with the project's gradle version.

Comment: thank you , but it downloads each time the gradle in wrapper , i mean I have several gradle in wrapper and it cant recognize them becuas the gradle are in graldle...-all folder

Comment: Made an edit. Hope that will give you more context.

Answer (score 0):

Beside what @karan dhilon said, you can go to Settings - > Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle and then select Specific location as shown in the pic. But for this you need a Gradle installed. You can dowload it from - [here](https://gradle.org/install/)

[image: Select Specific location]

Comment: I would not suggest to use custom gradle version usage as Gradle' s built in wrapper usage keeps its typesafe. Also, in case the original Gradle version is removed or updated, user would need to manually point the project to a new version. Gradle wrapper, however, takes care of that automatically.

Comment: I tried that but i have a question:  in (~.gradle\wrapper\dists) we should have gradle..-all folder or gradel.. folder(that doest have   -all word ) ??? does android studio recognize gradle..-all folder in wrapper?